# Running time analysis of Z3

Tags: z3, smt, sat

I'm using the Z3 SMT solver implemented through python. I have the source code, and I would like to have some, any, indication that the process is running. Is it possible to use some verbose command or anything to get an idea of what the process is currently doing? I know the algorithm behind it, but I want to visualize, even with printf, what is occurring in the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
      set_option(verbose=10)
```

to obtain verbose output to standard err.

After a solver has finished, you can get statistics using the

```
     statistics()
```

method.

In debug mode you can use

```
     enable_trace("arith")
```

to get low level traces (here given with "arith" as an example tag). 
This is intended for debugging only.

Comment: Thanks, that was a helpful starting point. What I'm really looking for now is the source file where the backtracing happens for the SAT solver. I thought SMT reduces to an SAT problem which then uses a backtracing like algorithm to look for solutions. I've found the c++ file sat_solver.cpp, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't get used when I run the example.py code. I really just want to print something like "backtracking" to console.